# How can I write a Lua script that will execute a command on the Linux terminal?

Tags: lua, scripting, command

I'm getting into scripting, and I understand the basics of Lua, but I don't know how I can run a command in the Linux terminal using Lua. When I say run a command I mean something like `sudo apt install git` or `echo Pizza is delicious`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options: if you want to run a lua script you have in a file `script.lua`, then `lua script.lua` should execute it. If you simply want to execute a couple of Lua statements, then you can use `-e` options: `lua -e "statement1; statement2"`. See the [Lua documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/1.4.html) for further details.

If you need to execute an external command from Lua, then you need to use [os.execute](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.execute): `os.execute([[echo "first param" "second param"]])`.